What is this usage of 何人いても?
「コタロウが可愛すぎてワンコは何人いてもいいなって思うよ」
「そうなんだ？　お迎えしたい？」
The character are talking about a dog. The owner says コタロウが可愛すぎて Kotaru is so cute...
But I'm slightly confused about the rest of the sentence.
"ワンコは何人いてもいい" the dog is fine no matter how many people are there? And what does お迎えしたい here mean? From google it seems to be used to go to animal shelters?
"何人" from context seem to be "many dogs" but I don't see why he'd use 人

Yes, I think it would be more understandable if it is ワンコは何匹いてもいいな
